# APFS decryption stuck

Tags: disk-utility, encryption, filevault, high-sierra, apfs

A week ago, I updated my Macbook Pro to 10.13 and reformatted both internal disks (SSH and HDD) to encrypted APFS. So far the SSD is working but I have a problem with the HDD. I can't mount the APFS volume from HDD to the system, it just takes too much time and nothing happens.

Running `diskutil repairvolume /dev/disk3` it gives this output:

```
Started file system repair on disk3
Repairing storage system
Performing fsck_apfs -y -x /dev/disk2s2
Checking volume
Checking the container superblock
Checking the space manager
Checking the object map
Checking the APFS volume superblock
Checking the object map
Checking the fsroot tree
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the extent ref tree
Checking the snapshots
Verifying allocated space
The volume /dev/disk2s2 appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
Finished file system repair on disk3
```

I've tried to mount HDD from Recovery mode and seems what it can't decrypt the volume. According to `diskutil apfs list` decryption stuck on 31%.

I've tried to reach Apple support, but they couldn't help me. What can be done next?

Answer (score 1):

Erase the volume. This can be done in Recovery Mode if necessary using the Terminal, which can be opened using the menu. Restore from a backup, then enable FileVault2, leaving the computer on and plugged in to allow the encryption to complete uninterrupted.

**This will erase all of the data on the volume you specify and leave behind an empty unencrypted volume:**

```
diskutil apfs eraseVolume <apfsVolumeDisk> -name <newName>
```

**Example:**

```
diskutil apfs /dev/disk2s2 -name "My HDD"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this a couple times when the machine wouldn’t start or hung at start. Also, consider that you might want to check for the number of snapshots before launching into the erase (or assume you aren’t making progress if there are 10 or even more snapshots - each will be checked if you are using Disk Utility to run First Aid.

Giving the Mac a chance to finish the check can yield results if you don’t want to just erase things and try to reinstall the OS.

I have a 2015 MBP that has 9 snapshots to check and each pass is taking about 20 minutes so this might be a long wait to get results.